# My website is working but links to it are not - DNS address could not be found

Tags: html, dns

I have just put online my first website and the home page address is https://www.hackingold.com/index.html .
If I manually write the address in the browser's address bar the website loads as expected. However, when I try to open it with a link from another application (such as whatsapp, or an email client), the browser can't reach the site and reports an error: "the DND address could not be found . DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE" . I could not figure out a solution by myself, though it might actually be really simple.
The site has https so the browser should see it as secure. I also tried to clear the browser cache etc. but it still does not work on my laptop neither on my mobile phone.
Thank you very much in advance.
Edoardo

Comment: Do you understand what [`DNS`](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/) are and what they are for?

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. This is my first website and I have a very basic knowledge of dns. I don't understand why the domain name points to the right IP when I write the address and does not work when I open it from a link. I am definetly check the guide you linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link has `www` in it, but the website address does not. This link works: https://hackingold.com/index.html

Comment: Thank you very much, if written this way the link actually works. I still don't get why It does so

Comment: because `www` is not used in every link. Your link was broken because it had extra letters, just like https://www.QQQ.google.com/ is broken

Comment: @edoardo.pastore Your DNS are provided by Epic Inc.  You need to discuss with them what URLs they are supposed to resolve.

Comment: Ok now I'm getting it, I will definitely recheck my setting on epics. Thank again!